# dataset dateTime Dbnull

Tags: .net, datetime, dataset, dbnull

How to get around the problem? When dbnul flies exception.

Answer (score 0):

A .net DateTime (which I assume you're talking about) can't be null. 
You can make it nullable by declaring it as a DateTime? which is equivalent to saying

```
Nullable<DateTime>
```